# MySqlConnection don't open

Tags: c#

How i should to fix that? I don't understand, please help me. Everything on photo. Cannot find database? or what?

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebAPI_GoCar.Model;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;

namespace WebAPI_GoCar.Controllers
{
    [Route("/[controller]")]
    public class ProfileController : Controller
    {
        private readonly string connectionString = "server=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root;database=GoCar;";
        
        // Получить все автомобили
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Profile> GetAllProfiles()
        {
            List<Profile> profiles = new List<Profile>();
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string query = "SELECT * FROM Users";
                MySqlCommand command = new(query, connection);
                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    profiles.Add(new Profile
                    {
                        Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                        Name = reader.GetString(1),
                        Surname = reader.GetString(2),
                        Email = reader.GetString(3),
                        Password = reader.GetString(4),
                        PhoneNumber = reader.GetString(5),
                        Date = reader.GetDateTime(6),
                    });
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            return profiles;
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should open up the `csproj` and add a reference to the required file `System.Security.Permissions` and reload the project.

Comment: `username=root;password=root;` - mmmhmmm

Comment: @RahulSharma didn't help

Comment: @Dai what did you want to say?

Comment: @ТарасГуледза Go to your Nuget Package manager and install this package :`System.Security.Permissions`

Comment: @RahulSharma i installed this package

Comment: "Version=0.0.0.0" looks strange, which version of the assembly do you reference? Do you have some binding redirects?

Comment: I think @Dai is expressing surprise that your root password is `root` which sounds highly insecure.